# can't log in to my EC2 windows instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've just created a windows EC2 instance. I got the password and downloaded the RDP shortcut. I tried to log in using the Administrator account and the provided password but it keep giving me a message saying that my credentials are wrong. What can I do? Amazon help just giving the simple steps that I did: 1) download the RDP shortcut, 2) retrieve the password using the .PEM file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a matter of time. I waited for some more time (although, it was ready and all checks are done), but just waited and that solved the issue.